# Little Problem by Searching Data without Alternate Data Streams with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ads

I'm testing loocking for my Alternate Data Streams an files that haven't ADS.

```
function recurse($path) {
    Pushd $path
    Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
        ForEach-Object {
            if (Get-Item -Literalpath $_.FullName -Stream Test-*) {
                Get-Item -Literalpath $_.FullName -Stream Test-*
            } else {
                Get-Item -Literalpath $_.FullName -Stream *
            }
        } |
        Select-Object FileName, Stream,
            @{n='Content';e={gc -Literalpath "$($_.FileName):$($_.Stream)"}} |
        Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 "C:\Temp\Streams.csv"
    Import-Csv "C:\Temp\Streams.csv"
}

recurse S:\Testing\Test_Tagging\6000_WK
```

The problem is that data without ADS is feeding my script with the stream `:$Data` and this takes a long time and doesn't look nice:

> FileName                                                  Stream
>   Content
>
> --------                                                  ------                        -------                                                                           S:\Testing\Test_Tagging\6000_WK\adfind.exe                :$DATA
>   MZ       ÿÿ  ¸       @                                     º
>   ´ Í!¸LÍ!... S:\Testing\Test_Tagging\6000_WK\admod.exe
>   :$DATA                        MZP      ÿÿ  ¸       @
>     º ´ Í!¸LÍ!... S:\Testing\Test_Tagging\6000_WK\Athens
>   Test-Classification.txt       vertraulich
>   S:\Testing\Test_Tagging\6000_WK\Athens                    Test-KSU.txt
>   0.2 Temporär                                                 S:\Testing\Test_Tagging\6000_WK\mariadb-10.4.8-winx64.msi :$DATA
>   ÐÏà¡±á                >  þÿ
>   þÿÿÿ      ...
>   S:\Testing\Test_Tagging\6000_WK\mariadb-10.4.8-winx64.msi
>   Zone.Identifier              ZoneTransfer]
>   S:\Testing\Test_Tagging\6000_WK\SumSum.txt
>   Test-Classification.txt       vertraulich
>   S:\Testing\Test_Tagging\6000_WK\SumSum.txt                Test-KSU.txt
>   0.2 Temporär                                                 S:\Testing\Test_Tagging\6000_WK[666]\Athens
>   Test-Classification.txt       vertraulich
>   S:\Testing\Test_Tagging\6000_WK[666]\Athens              Test-KSU.txt
>   0.2 Temporär                                                 S:\Testing\Test_Tagging\6000_WK[]\Athens
>   Test-Classification.txt       vertraulich
>   S:\Testing\Test_Tagging\6000_WK[]\Athens                 Test-KSU.txt
>   0.2 Temporär

The best way is when files without ADS only shows the name and no stream and no data.

Can anyone help me to become something like this:

```
FileName                                                  Stream                        Content                                                                          
--------                                                  ------                        -------                                                                          
S:\Testing\Test_Tagging\6000_WK\adfind.exe                
S:\Testing\Test_Tagging\6000_WK\admod.exe                 
S:\Testing\Test_Tagging\6000_WK\Athens                    Test-Classification.txt       vertraulich                                                                      
S:\Testing\Test_Tagging\6000_WK\Athens                    Test-KSU.txt                  0.2 Temporär                                                
S:\Testing\Test_Tagging\6000_WK\mariadb-10.4.8-winx64.msi 
S:\Testing\Test_Tagging\6000_WK\mariadb-10.4.8-winx64.msi Zone.Identifier              ZoneTransfer]                                                          
S:\Testing\Test_Tagging\6000_WK\SumSum.txt                Test-Classification.txt       vertraulich                                                                      
S:\Testing\Test_Tagging\6000_WK\SumSum.txt                Test-KSU.txt                  0.2 Temporär                                                
S:\Testing\Test_Tagging\6000_WK\[666]\Athens              Test-Classification.txt       vertraulich                                                                      
S:\Testing\Test_Tagging\6000_WK\[666]\Athens              Test-KSU.txt                  0.2 Temporär                                                
S:\Testing\Test_Tagging\6000_WK\[]\Athens                 Test-Classification.txt       vertraulich                                                                      
S:\Testing\Test_Tagging\6000_WK\[]\Athens                 Test-KSU.txt                  0.2 Temporär
```

Answer (score 0):

`:$Data` is the "regular" content of the file. Simply omit reading that stream in your calculated property.

```
... |
Select-Object FileName, Stream,
    @{n='Content';e={
        if ($_.Stream -ne ':$Data') {
            Get-Content -Literalpath "$($_.FileName):$($_.Stream)"
        }
    }} |
...
```